# Can I alert() all elements of a javascript array in a single alert?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple HTML table like this:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th id="lname"><span title="sort this column">Last Name</span>
            </th>
            <th id="fname"><span title="sort this column">First Name</span>
            </th>
            <th id="scanned"><span title="sort this column">Scanned In</span>
            </th>
            <th id="department"><span title="sort this column">Department</span>
            </th>
            <th id="category"><span title="sort this column">Category</span>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="blah">LNAME1</td>
            <td>FNAME1</td>
            <td>06/25/13 12:48 PM</td>
            <td>Internal Medicine</td>
            <td>Fellow</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="blah">LNAME1</td>
            <td>FNAME1</td>
            <td>06/25/13 12:48 PM</td>
            <td>Internal Medicine</td>
            <td>Fellow</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="blah">LNAME1</td>
            <td>FNAME1</td>
            <td>06/26/13 07:29 AM</td>
            <td>Internal Medicine</td>
            <td>Faculty</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="blah">LNAME1</td>
            <td>FNAME1</td>
            <td>06/26/13 07:21 AM</td>
            <td>Internal Medicine</td>
            <td>Faculty</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And a javascript/jquery code going something like this:

```
var count = 0;
var scannedArr = new Array();
$('table tr').each(function(){
    var times = $(this).find('.blah').text();
    scannedArr[count] = times;
    count++;
});
```

What I'm trying to do in this javascript function is include the `scannedArr` array's elements all in a single alert(). Can I do that? Is there a simpler way to go about it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: say, alert(scannedArr )

Comment: Does `alert(scannedArr)` not work for you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
alert(scannedArr.join(''));
```

Comment: I really would recommend a non-empty separator :-) Try `'\n'` instead

Comment: @Bergi it depends on what the op is needing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `join()` to create single string of your array:

```
// using comma as a separtor
// you can pass any separator as: join('separator')
var everything = scannedArr.join();
alert(everything);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```
var tableStuff = $('table tr').map(function(){
    return $(this).find('.blah').text();
}).get();

alert(tableStuff);
```

Now `tableStuff` is a nice array of the text from `.blah`

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use:

```
alert(JSON.stringify(scannedArr));
```

Comment: or better yet, alert(JSON.stringify(scannedArr), null, '\t');

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:

```
function printObject(o) {
  var out = '';
  for (var p in o) {
    out += p + ': ' + o[p] + '\n';
  }
  alert(out);
}
```

But, i like more use `console.log(array)`, with chrome (and you can see in the js console!)

Comment: Aps, and for open the console, ctrl + shift + j

Answer (score 0):

```
    var count = 0;
    var scannedArr = new Array[];
    $('table tr').each(function(){
        var times = $(this).find('.blah').text();

    scannedArr.push(times)
        count++;
    });

alert(scannedArr);
```